# How to detect when project was moved to a new location

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

It seems that it isn't possible to detect if a project was moved from one location to another location by using an `IResourceChangeListener`.

For example, when changing the project's location from `/old/path/to/project` to `/new/path/to/project` with the `MoveProjectOperation`, the event details look like this:

```
name = project-name
kind = CHANGE 
flags = DESCRIPTION  
movedFromPath = null 
movedToPath = null 
location = /new/path/to/project
```

However, the same event details are sent when the project description was changed for some other reason.

The JavaDoc of `IResourceDelta::getFlags()` and a [forum post](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/37109/) give a hint that there is a `MOVED_FROM` flag and `getMovedFromPath()` will return the path of where a resource was moved from. But I didn't see any such event.

Is there really no way to tell if a project is moved or am I missing something? If there is a workaround I would also be glad to head about.

Comment: Are these locations outside of the workspace so the logical location in the workspace doesn't change?

Comment: Yes, the locations may be outside of the workspace, but I've also the case that a project located within the workspace is moved outside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have found a workaround. The fix is to maintain a snapshot of current project descriptions (`IProjectDescription`). A project description also contains the project location.

The snapshot would need to be updated when the *move detection code* starts and whenever a new project was created.

Whenever a `DESCRIPTION` change event as described in the question occurs, I can compare the `project.getLocationURI()` with the location of the project description from the snapshot. If they differ, the project was moved. Otherwise, an uninteresting change occurred.